# Why can't use the external SD card with my voice recorder app?

Tags: external-sd, voice-recording

I'm the owner of an Honor 5x.

The external SD card inside the phone works fine with the photos/video application, and I can write/read from ES file manager *but* the apps for voice recording that I tried (Total Recall, Voice Recorder, RecForge) don't let me save the file on the external SD.

Can anyone help me and/or explain what's happening?

Comment: What version of Android? On Marshmallow, apps request permission to access SD Card. If the apps don't request, are aren't designed to target Android M, the OS won't allow the apps to access the SD card

Comment: The versione is Lollipop (5.1.1).

Comment: [How to save files to external SD card on a non-rooted Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218338/218526)